# Function not working but parts do work separately

Tags: javascript, function

This routine is to be part of a web page that will allow users to compile a list of artwork they are interested in by clicking a button next to a work. The list on screen will dynamically update.

My first version had 'add' and 'remove' in two different functions. The responses were hardcoded in an href (addTo removeFrom):

```
addToList('artlist','Painting #1')
removeFromList('artlist','')

function addToList(id,listEntry) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    container.innerHTML = listEntry;
}

function removeFromList(id,listEntry) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    container.innerHTML = listEntry;
}
```

It worked.

Then this was updated: An array holding a list was added (like what might be the user's previous choices, and a new selection was put into a variable to simulate an active choice.

But there were problems:

1. The functions each repeated the guts of the routine

   ```
   var screenList = document.getElementById(id); 
   screenList.innerHTML = listEntry;
   ```
2. The user could erase the list by hitting the 'remove' button until it was empty, or adding the new selection and then 'remove'”
3. The user could just keep adding the new selection over and over.

Attempted to combine them in a new function and using a 'key' variable to disallow adding the new selection more than once and only allowing the new selection to be removed once, so the user could change his/her mind.

I found out about push, pop and innerhtml (when I first tried my hand at javascript years ago these were not around - yeah, I know, I'm old) and was able to move the "container" section out to where I needed it only once.

```
var workList = ["Man in Blue", "A Collection of Portraits"];
var work = "Stand Out";

function addremove(id,listEntry) {  
    if (typeof key === 'undefined') { // first time through set list with  no change
        var key = 0;                  // intitialize key, key=0, can add selection, key=1 already added
    } else if (key === 0) {           // add user selection to list
        workList.push(work);
        key = key++;                  // key=1 selection added don't add again
    } else if (key === 1) {           // allow user to change mind and remove selection
        workList.pop();
        key = key--;                  // key=0 selection removed - can be added again
    }

    var screenList = document.getElementById(id); // add list to div - artlist
    screenList.innerHTML = listEntry;
}
```

With this version I can get the list to populate when key is undefined but I cannot get a selection added or removed. I ran a test with the console running and no errors or other problems showed up. I figure it's a logic problem but I can't see what needs to be changed.

Comment: You're only ever defining `key` **inside** your function so it will always be `undefined`

Comment: Also, `key = key++` won't do anything as `key++` returns the old value of `key` (same for `k--`). You just want `k++` or `k--` on their own (or `k = k + 1` / `k = k - 1`)

Comment: @Prisoner it **is** declared in the function

Comment: Ah, you're right. I sit corrected.

Answer (score 0):

@Phil @Prisoner Thanks for the help. Here is the working routine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var workList = ["Man in Blue", "A Collection of Portraits"];
var work = "Stand Out";
var key = 3;                        // initialize key, key=0, can add selection, key=1 already added

function addremove(id,listEntry) {  

    if (key == 0) {                 // add selection to list
        workList.push(work);
        key++;                      // key=1 selection added don't add again
    } else if (key == 1) {          // allow user to change mind and remove selection
        workList.pop();
        key--;                      // key=0 selection removed - can be added again
    }else if (key == 3) {           // first time through set list with  no change
        key = 0;                          
    }

    var screenList = document.getElementById(id); // add list to div - artlist
    screenList.innerHTML = listEntry;
}
</script>
```

In the declaration I gave key a value of 3 and got rid of "undefined."

The change of key to 0 was moved to the bottom. (Don't know if that does anything but it looks better to me.

"key = key++" changed to "key++"

It all works. It is nice to get some fresh eyes looking at it.
Thanks again!